# QGIS keeps crashing when exporting print layout map - how to stop this?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, export, print-composer, svg

When exporting my map which contains vector data and two maps (one as a global locator insert map) as an SVG file QGIS keeps crashing. I need the map to be exported as an SVG file as I want to edit it further in Inkscape. What could be the sources of the crashing? How can I fix this? I'm using QGIS desktop 3.10.6.

Comment: Did you try to export the vector layers separately? You than could bring it together in Inkscape again.